# Looping through a dictionary in python

Tags: python, string, csv, dictionary, count

I am creating a main function which loops through dictionary that has one key for all the values associated with it. I am having trouble because I can not get the dictionary to be all lowercase. I have tried using .lower but to no avail. Also, the program should look at the words of the sentence, determine whether it has seen more of those words in sentences that the user has previously called "happy", "sad", or "neutral", (based on the three dictionaries) and make a guess as to which label to apply to the sentence.

an example output would be like

```
Sentence: i started screaming incoherently about 15 mins ago, this is B's attempt to calm me down.
  0 appear in happy
  0 appear in neutral
  0 appear in sad
I think this is sad.
You think this is: sad
Okay! Updating.
```

**CODE:**

```
import csv

def read_csv(filename, col_list):
"""This function expects the name of a CSV file and a list of strings
representing a subset of the headers of the columns in the file, and
returns a dictionary of the data in those columns, as described below."""

    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        # Better covert reader to a list (items represent every row)
        reader = list(csv.DictReader(f))
        dict1 = {}
        for col in col_list:
            dict1[col] = []
            # Going in every row of the file
            for row in reader:
                # Append to the list the row item of this key
                dict1[col].append(row[col])
    return dict1

def main():
    dictx = read_csv('words.csv', ['happy'])
    dicty = read_csv('words.csv', ['sad'])
    dictz = read_csv('words.csv', ['neutral'])
    dictxcounter = 0
    dictycounter = 0
    dictzcounter = 0
    a=str(raw_input("Sentence: ")).split(' ')
    for word in a :
        for keys in dictx['happy']:
            if word == keys:
                 dictxcounter = dictxcounter + 1
        for values in dicty['sad']:
            if word == values:
                 dictycounter = dictycounter + 1
        for words in dictz['neutral']:
            if word == words:
                dictzcounter = dictzcounter + 1
    print dictxcounter
    print dictycounter
    print dictzcounter
```

Comment: If `col_list` is a list of _one_ string, this expression must crash because of unpacking error: `dict1=dict((k, v.lower()) for k,v in col_list)`. Are you sure you are showing us correct code? The same statement also overwrites the dictionary that you built in the loop, which probably explains why your code doesn't work as expected.

Comment: What you pass to `read_csv` _is_ a list of one string: `['happy']`. And this list becomes the value of the formal parameter `col_list`.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by >>>, but the way your program is written now, `col_list` is a list of one string.

Comment: For example: read_csv('words.csv', ['happy']) yields 
{'happy': ['ADORED', 'ADORING', 'ADORINGLY', 'ADVANCED'...

Comment: OK, but how would I create the whole thing to be lowercase?

Comment: `dict1[col].append(row[col].lower())`. You also need to lowercase the user input before splitting it. And for the reference, function `str()` on the user input line is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line from your code:

```
dict1 = dict((k, v.lower()) for k,v in col_list)
```

It overwrites the dictionary that you built in the loop.